# Iframe resize on firefox, only extending not shrinking

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, cross-domain

Hello im working on a iframe resize for cross browser apps. IE, Firefox, Chrome ans Safari specifically.

Resize works well on IE but not on the others. On the others work partially. What is happening is that when you expand the iframe it cannot be shrinked or reduce. The code I am using in the iframed page is bringing back the last and highest value used. So every time I update the size, it brings thesame value.

Here is the code im using for this:

Parent:
Main.asp

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
<title>iframe  Resize A</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<iframe frameborder="1" id="iframetest" src="http://localhost/testing1/iframed.html"></iframe>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//Create IE + others compatible event handler
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

//Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
//console.log('parent received message!:  ', e.data);
//console.log('parent received message!:  ', e.origin);

    var currH = 1700;
    var rcvH = parseInt ( e.data, 10 ); 

    //Verificando el origen
    if (e.origin == "http://localhost")
    {
        if (rcvH != undefined | | rcvH > 0 ) {
                document.getElementById('iframetest').style.height = (rcvH) + 'px';
    }
    else {
       document.getElementById('iframetest').height = currH + 'px';
    }
}
}, false); 
</script>
</body>
</html >
```

Iframed
Iframed.html

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>CampaĆƒĀ±as de SelecciĆƒĀ³n</TITLE>
<style type="text/css">
#tabdata h1
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold; 
}

#tabdata div{
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    padding-top:0px;
    font-size:12px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    border-top:0px;
}

#tabs-2, #tabs-3
{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="css/myapp.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.8.11/jquery-ui-1.8.11/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.11/jquery-ui-1.8.11/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY id="bcname">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="tabdata">

<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="javascript: showHide('tabs-1');">Test</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="javascript: showHide('tabs-2');">Test 2</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void();" onclick="javascript: void ( ); " onclick="javascript : showHide ('tabs-3'); " > Test 3 </a> </li>
        </ul>
        </td>
    </tr >
    <tr>
        <td><div id="tabs-1">Test #1</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><div id="tabs-2">Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2TestTest #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2TestTest #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2Test<p>Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2TestTest #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2Test</p><p>Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2TestTest #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2Test</p><p>Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2TestTest #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br /> Test #2Test #2Test #2Test</p><p>Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2TestTest #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2Test</p><p>Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2TestTest #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2Test</p><p>Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2TestTest #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2Test</p>Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2<br />Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2Test #2</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="tabs-3">Test #3</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHide(lkObj) {
    var x = new Array("tabs-1", "tabs-2", "tabs-3");

for(ic=0;ic<3;ic++){
    if(x[ic]==lkObj){
        document.getElementById(x[ic]).style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(x[ic]).style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function adjust_iframe_height() {
    var actual_height = document.body.scrollHeight;
    parent.postMessage(actual_height, "*");
    //* allows this to post to any parent iframe regardless of domain
}

setTimeout(adjust_iframe_height, 2000);

document.onclick = function () {     
adjust_iframe_height();
}

</script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fou d the answer to my problem, its very simple. The only change I had to make to the iframed script is instead of using the document.body.scrollHeight, I used the height of the div element containing all the content. Using now document.getElementById ('divname').scrollHeight; that worked for me. I will add the complete aolution once a get a computer. Im using the android app of stack exchange.